# Connect Wall - find the groups

Tags: connect-wall

This is my first attempt at an only connect wall and honestly, I expect it to be solved within the hour, if not the first 10 minutes.

> ```
> |  Angel    |  Hollywood  |  Werewolf   |  Heron     |
> |  Starling |  Goose      |  Walker     |  Rudd      |
> |  Sheriff  |  Moorhen    |  McCartney  |  Doctor    |
> |  Jester   |  Beast      |  Iceman     |  Gambit    |
> ```

Rules:

> The 16 words above can be split into 4 different categories, each with 4 words in it.
>   Your task is to present the words sorted into their categories with an explanation of what the categories are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it?:

> `McCartney | Walker | Rudd | Hollywood` -Stars(TV/music) named Paul
>  `Goose | Moorhen | Heron | Starling` -  Birds
>  `Werewolf | Doctor | Jester | Sheriff` - Roles from Town of Salem
>  `Angel | Iceman | Gambit | Beast` - Marvel Characters/X-Men

Comment: Perfect, well done! Can you spot the hidden 5th group as well? (which takes one from each of the other groups)

Comment: At first glance i see a connection to Destiny 2: Walker (enemy), Starling (Starling Bolt - legendary Sparrow ), Jester (Gemini Jester - Exotic boots for hunter), Gambit (game mode). But i'm not sure about that :)

Comment: that's not it :)

Comment: @AHKieran - Im going to go with Top Gun character nicknames?

Answer (score 11):

I only got one group, and it wasn't even right, but anyway - here's the hidden fifth group:

> Goose, Iceman, Jester, Hollywood - nicknames of Pilots in Top Gun

Do I win a wooden spoon or something?

Comment: There is no Wolfman on the wall but the other four are the intended hidden group, well done :D

Comment: I removed Wolfman, got that one muddled up with Werewolf.

Answer (score 3):

First group:

> **Professions**: Sheriff, Doctor, Iceman, Jester

Second group:

> **Birds**: Starling, Moorhen, Goose, Heron

Third group:

> **Supernatural beings**: Angel, Beast, Werewolf, Gambit

Fourth group:

> **Surnames**: Hollywood, McCartney, Rudd, Walker

Comment: 2 out of 4 groups correct, nice try!